# Need an explanation of Cross-Site Flashing?

Tags: xss, flash

[I found this](http://demo.testfire.net/vulnerable.swf) - can anyone provide me examples of how these issues are exploited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Flash is jailed by the some-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_Flash) and can only act upon a site that loads the flash applet with scripting access enabled.

However,  flash can become a vector for XSS.  The demo above lists [various XSS vectors](http://demo.testfire.net/vulnerable.swf).  So for example in the extremely unlikely condition where you are loading a flash applet where the attacker can control the `loadMovieNumVar` variable then an attacker could execute JavaScript in the context of the site by setting this variable to `javascript:alert('gotcha!')`.

XSS is extremely common and there are many ways that this attack can manifest. Flash based XSS is one way,  and its also extremely uncommon.

Comment: So if attacker finds url like this : http://demo.testfire.net/vulnerable.swf?loadMovieNumVar=XSS he can try to exploit xss issue?

Comment: @user1203028 No...  flash doesn't usually accept GET parameters like that,  that is usually used by server-side code.  Flash accepts these parameters defined in the `<object>` tag.

Comment: So if user input is reflected anywhere inside these dangerous parameters , than XSS can be exploited.Since GET is not an option.

Comment: @user1203028 yep